# Python __getattr__ behavior? IN ECLIPSE/PyDev console?

Tags: python, pydev, getattr

The following:

```
class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return self.__dict__[attr]
        except KeyError:
            self.__dict__[attr] = 'Attribute set to string'
            print 'Assigned attribute'
            return self.__dict__[attr]
```

returns:

```
obj = A()
obj.foo
Assigned attribute
Assigned attribute
Assigned attribute
'Attribute set to string'
```

Where is the magic happening?

(I'm on 2.6.6)

**Edit**: Thanks for your feedback. Indeed, this problem can't be reproduced from the Python command line itself. It seems that it only occurs when using the console in Eclipse/PyDev.

Comment: For me, it only prints `Assigned attribute` once.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with python 2.5, 2.6, or 3.1. Try "print 'looking for', attr" after the def \_\_getattr\_\_ line to see what's wanted.

Comment: Ok this is strange. It printed out three times in the Eclipse console, but using the interpreter from the command shell it behaves correctly.

Comment: If you can reproduce this, do smth like `[k, a.__dict__[k] for k in a.__dict__.keys()]` and see which other attributes were set. Then you could think of why.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess here (I don't use eclipse) and say that perhaps eclipse is calling `hasattr` on your object for code completion, etc?  `hasattr` is implemented by trying `getattr`...

Comment: Come to think of it, that is a very plausible explanation.

Comment: If it's for code completion then it's probably looking for "\_\_methods\_\_" and "\_\_members\_\_". Again, print attr to see what it's asking for.

Comment: In the console, when requesting a code-completion or hover, it'll do a dir() in the object (that's the reason you have more getattrs in that object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't happen:

```
class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return self.__dict__[attr]
        except KeyError:
            self.__dict__[attr] = 'Attribute set to string'
            print 'Assigned attribute'
            return self.__dict__[attr]

obj = A()
print obj.foo
```

gives:

```
Assigned attribute
Attribute set to string
```

`__getattr__` is only called when the attribute does not exist! So the `try .. except` will go into the except every time ...

It's equivalent to:

```
class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        val = 'Attribute set to string'
        setattr(self, attr, val)
        print 'Assigned attribute'
        return val
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a slightly different version of your code that might help.

```
class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return self.__dict__[attr]
        except KeyError:
            self.__dict__[attr] = 'Attribute set to string'
            print 'Assigned attribute', attr
            return self.__dict__[attr]

>>> o = A()
>>> o.foo
Assigned attribute foo
'Attribute set to string'
```

I don't know how you see "Assigned attribute" more than once though. This is with Python 2.6.6.

It's worth pointing out that the `try` always fails if `__getattr__` is called.